# ZF2: how can the Application ServiceManager be configured to auto-add classes?

Tags: zend-framework2, service-locator

`AbstractPluginManager` has an interesting property called `$autoAddInvokableClass` which, when enabled, automatically adds any class you attempt to invoke to its list of invokables. Unfortunately, as far as I know, this behaviour is not implemented by ServiceManager itself.

What would be the best way to implement this behaviour in the Application's ServiceManager such that `$applicationServiceManager->get(SomeUnregisteredClass::class)` would load `SomeUnregisteredClass` even without registering it with `$applicationServiceManager` and therefore still run any relevant initializers on the object?

Attempting to do this without registering `SomeUnregisteredClass` normally throws an exception similar to the following.

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for SomeUnregisteredClass

Comment: Believe me, you do not want that feature!

Comment: Well, if you think that is absolutely necessary then you can create abstract factory as fallback which will try to instantiate anything you throw at it. But be warned, you are about to shoot yourself in the leg.

Comment: For now I have created an abstract factory that loads a given namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please realise all the possibilities you create with this feature: do you really need this?

Then, the "root" service manager does not have a `autoAddInvokableClass` property. You can, however, create your own service manager and register that as the default one.

Create your custom one:

```
<?php
namespace MyLib\ServiceManager;

use Zend\ServiceManager as BaseServiceManager;

class ServiceManager extends BaseServiceManager
{
    protected $autoAddInvokableClass = true;

    public function get($name, $options = array(), $usePeeringServiceManagers = true)
    {
        // Allow specifying a class name directly; registers as an invokable class
        if (!$this->has($name) && $this->autoAddInvokableClass && class_exists($name)) {
            $this->setInvokableClass($name, $name);
        }

        return parent::get($name, $options, $usePeeringServiceManagers);
    }
}
```

Mind that **ALL** service managers will extend from this one, including the controllers loader. So if you have a route `/foo/:controller[/:action]` you can load **ANY** class this way as you specify a FQCN in the `:controller` parameter!

Anyhow, that being said, just enable this SM in your application config:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        // Your module here
    ),

    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
    ),

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    'service_listener_options' => array(
        array(
            'service_manager' => 'MyLib\ServiceManager\ServiceManager',
        ),
    ),
);
```